# What would make a MySQL database create tables in a different collation other than its default?

Tags: mysql, collation

I am adding tables to a Wordpress database on my localhost and it is changing my collation from `utf8_general_ci` to `latin1_swedish_ci`.  I'm kinda stumped because I'm not familiar with working directly with databases since I am new to them.  Could you explain why this happens?

My default character set is `utf8` and my collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

Also, when I use the same code to create a table in other databases it works correctly.

HOLY CRAP I just now tried using wordpresses $wpdb class and it is doing the SAME THING!  What the crap!

FOUND ANSWER AT WORDPRESS ANSWERS ---- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5927/default-table-collation-on-plugin-activation?rq=1

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: What is the default collation for your database?

Comment: My default character set is utf8 and my collate is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: This very much so makes no sense at all.  I am, using the same exact class I wrote, creating tables in other databases and it is creating them with the correct data.

Comment: If you really found an answer, please, answer your question in a proper answer.  You can even accept it afterwards.

Comment: @dezso I guess I will... Just thought that would be crappy giving myself points.  But uh alright.

Comment: You don't get rep just from answering and accepting your answer.  If others think it is worth upvoting than it means that the answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally actually adding this to the question.
You must specify the COLLATION while creating the table. It will inherit the collation from the database which is latin1_swedish_ci. Wordpress sets the collation only for the connection, not for the database. E.g. for WHERE or ORDER BY clauses... See Answer and comment similar to this in link above.

hrake gets the credit not I